# How to force partition to value out of range

Tags: partitioning, partition-recovery, fdisk, parted

I have an ubuntu desktop system (VM guest), whose partitions were created by the install media. I wanted to expand the disk, so I shutdown the guest, and increased the disk size of the guest in the host. Now I need to expand the partitions in the guest - and here's the problem:

If I print the original table, this is what I get:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 37.6 GB, 37580963840 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4568 cylinders, total 73400320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    41940991    20719617    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760    41940991    20719616   8e  Linux LVM
```

In the past, whenever I've needed to expand a partition, I would delete and recreate the partition with the same type, and the same start, but different end. It's not working this time:

```
Command (m for help): d
Partition number (1-5): 5

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 1 extended, 2 free)
   l   logical (numbered from 5)
Select (default p): l
Adding logical partition 5
First sector (503806-41940991, default 503806): 501760
Value out of range.
```

Whaaat? How is it possible that I can't create a partition with the parameters that it had just a second ago? In any event, I quit. I thought maybe it was just an old fdisk, so I dug myself deeper into the hole:

I used parted to delete the partition, not knowing that it would apply the change instantly. (I expected it to require "write" or "apply" command when I was finished ... So I screwed up.) Now my original partition is deleted and I can't recreate it.

How can I force creation of a partition with value out of range?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrinking ext4 partition: fdisk won't allow to recreate the partition at the same start block](https://superuser.com/questions/687200/shrinking-ext4-partition-fdisk-wont-allow-to-recreate-the-partition-at-the-sam). My solution with `fdisk` should work in cases like yours as well.

Answer (score 8):

Got it. This worked for me:

By launching `sudo parted` I was able to do `unit s` to switch to sectors, and `p` to see the current table, and `mkpart logical 501760 41940991` to recreate the partition. And quit from parted. Then I ran `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and used `t` to set the partition type back to `8e`

Comment: Since I just went through this, a reminder that if the partition you are recreating should be marked active, while you have fdisk open to set the type is the perfect time to double check that :D

Answer (score 1):

I get in the exact same situation. I wanted to extend an LVM partition of a virtual machine with the layout as shown in question (msdos style). While the author resolved it using parted instead of fdisk, it is also possible to do with fdisk.

I have found a solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320201/how-to-extend-logical-extended-partition-with-fdisk) (so go there and upvote for the original answerer too). The problem is that you need to also resize /sda2, which is your "extended" partition that contains your sda5 logical partition.

After that, follow [this](https://www.ryadel.com/en/resize-extend-disk-partition-unallocated-disk-space-linux-centos-rhel-ubuntu-debian/) article to grow lvm pv, lvm lv, and finally your fs.